# Video turns (almost) black and white after plugging in laptop power

Tags: windows-8.1, colors, windows-media-player

When plugging in power to a Toshiba Satellite, video in Windows Media Player (Windows 8.1) suddenly turns almost black and white. Some color is still visible, but it's clearly less colorful than before (see example below). It turns colorful again when power is plugged out. When the video is paused, color does not change until the video is resumed. Upon resuming, it changes immediately. When playing, the change takes about half a second to come into effect.

This does not happen in VLC. It happens for at least two unrelated .avi files, stored on a different device (external HDD vs internal).

What could possibly be going on and how could I solve this?

[image: blacky whitey]
[image: colors <3]